# Where can I buy an "unmodified" star wars episode 4-6 copy?

Tags: star-wars

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I'd like to watch pre-“Special Edition” Star Wars, what is the best source/transfer?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1472/id-like-to-watch-pre-special-edition-star-wars-what-is-the-best-source-transf)

Every couple of years Star Wars is re-released... and when it gets re-released there are modifications. EX: dvd edition had new CG stuff added. EX: bluray edition has darth vader saying "noo" during very important scene.

Each modification is very small (except Vader saying "noo" modification) if examined by itself... but when you add them all together... the sum of all the small modifications makes the current bluray edition significantly different from the original version displayed in theatres the first time.

**Where can I buy an "unmodified" star wars episode 4-6 copy?**

**If there is no way to buy an unmodified version. What commercially released version of star wars trilogy episode 4-6 has the least modifications?**

definitions:

- commercially released means: official mass production run of some sort. either beta, laser disc, dvd, bluray, etc.
- unmodified means: the same as the cinematic version