# Is there a version of A New Hope with most/all the deleted scenes edited in?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, deleted-scenes

After reading [this question about a deleted scene in A New Hope](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46617/star-wars-scene-where-luke-skywalker-witnesses-battle-above-tatooine), I noticed there seem to be many scenes that were filmed but not included, some of which I knew about and others I didn't. It made me think it'd be fun to watch an edit that had the 1970's version plus all the watchable outtakes. Has anyone made such an edit?

(This seems fairly likely, given that I know fans have made re-edits of several Star Wars films, such as "The Phantom Edit" (reducing Gungans and other annoyances) and unmodified original trilogy versions ([Where can I buy an "unmodified" star wars episode 4-6 copy?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5610/where-can-i-buy-an-unmodified-star-wars-episode-4-6-copy?rq=1)).)

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware. You can watch almost all the deleted scenes [online](http://www.dailymotion.com/twenty24) but I don't know if anyone's created a fan-edit with those scenes included.

Comment: "Is there"? Indubitably, yes. Is it available legally? LucasFilm's lawyers and Youtube's cowardice say "likely, no".

Comment: "Star Wars : Deleted Magic" is widely available on all good torrent websites. I suspect that's as close as you're gonna get.

Comment: @DVK Would LucasFilm dislike such an edit more than others such as The Phantom Edit or Harmy's Despecialized Editions?

Comment: Doesn't the special edition that has been around lately and also shown on tv have all the outtakes in it?

Comment: @Thomas I don't know. Did it have 9:29 of Luke talking to his friend Biggs on Tatooine? Here are nine scenes: http://www.dailymotion.com/playlist/x25txl_twenty24_star-wars-iv-deleted-scenes/1#video=xs9p70 and I think there are a few more, such as at least one on Yavin discussing Luke flying in the Death Star attack. Also I assume any current special edition has all the new additions too, no?

Comment: Hmmm biggs on tatooine I'm not 100% but else: I saw han talking to jabba, and also the discussion about luke on yavin. Those two I remember off the hat seeing. need to look up what the other 6 are though (will do so in the afternoon)

Comment: The radio drama has many of these scenes (and more).

Comment: No, the Special Editions do not have everything that was cut. The most recent blu-rays include many of the missing scenes included for viewing, but not edited back into the movies.

Comment: @DVK _Youtube's cowardice_?? You wouldn't be afraid of being sued into oblivion by an army of lawyers from LucasFilm? You are a braver man than I!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No. No such thing exists, at least in a legal format.** (and likely never will given Lucasfilm's [extreme reaction](http://www.filmthreat.com/news/561/) to other feature-length fanedits).

If you want to view the deleted scenes, you can <s>buy</s> (* ahem *) acquire a copy of *[Star Wars : Deleted Magic](https://archive.org/details/star-wars-deleted-magic)* from a number of sources. Note that many of these extra scenes are in extremely poor 'rough-cut' quality and could never be inserted into a genuine copy of Star Wars without massively interupting the dramatic flow.

Many of these scenes are also available on the [Daily Motion](http://www.dailymotion.com) site, again in varying levels of film quality ranging from bad to worse.

---

Failing that, the [Radio Dramatisations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Esvn5gT9vIQ) and [Star Wars novelisations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Wars_books) contain a number of scenes that were filmed but ultimately not included in the final cut.